# Segmentation fault - while using librsync library

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, rsync, librsync

I have two base file `filea.txt` and `fileb.txt`. Trying to create signature, then delta using signature and `fileb.txt`, then patch `filea.txt` with that delta. Resulting file's contents should be same as `fileb.txt`

First part creates signature file from `filea.txt`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "librsync.h"

int main(){
    FILE *fpa;
    fpa = fopen("filea.txt","r");

    FILE *fps;
    fps = fopen("sig.sig","w+");


    rs_result res = rs_sig_file(fpa, fps, 1,2,NULL);

    fclose(fpa);
    fclose(fps);

    printf("Result code: %d\n", res);

    return 0;
}
```

Then the second one is supposed to use that signature with `fileb.txt` file to create delta file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "librsync.h"


int main(){
    FILE *fpb;
    fpb = fopen("fileb.txt", "r");

    FILE *fpd;
    fpd = fopen("delta.delt","w+");

    FILE *sigFile;
    sigFile = fopen("sig.sig","r");

    rs_signature_t *signature;

    rs_loadsig_file(sigFile, &signature, NULL);

    rs_result res = rs_delta_file(signature, fpb, fpd, NULL);

    printf("Result: %d", res);

    fclose(fpb); fclose(fpd); fclose(sigFile);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling both of them like this
gcc -o delta create_delta.c -Wall -g -lrsync

But the second part gives Segmentation fault error.

Maybe because of this, third executable produces empty file:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fpd;
    fpd = fopen("delta.delt", "r");

    FILE *fpa;
    fpa = fopen("filea.txt", "r");

    FILE *fpn;
    fpn = fopen("file_new.txt", "w+");

    rs_patch_file(fpa, fpd, fpn, NULL);

    fclose(fpd); fclose(fpa); fclose(fpn);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Tried checking file pointers for null after fopen didn't catch any errors.

Comment: You have absolutely no error checking on any of your calls to the standard library or to the rsync library functions `rs_loadsig_file`, `rs_patch_file`, etc - how do you expect to catch any problems ?

Comment: Tried checking file pointers for null after fopen didn't catch any errors.

Comment: What about the rsync library calls though, particularly `rs_loadsig_file` ?

Comment: `printf` just after `rs_loadsig_file` doesn't work. So I think `rs_loadsig_file` is making that error

Comment: OK - run under gdb - hit `bt` when you crash, then see if the resulting backtrace gives any clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at https://rproxy.samba.org/doxygen/librsync/rsync_h.html i figured you have to use

> rs_build_hash_table(signature)

before calling

> rs_delta_file(signature, fpb, fpd, NULL);

Works fine for me then.